# Dynamic size styling in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have searched for this, I got the some idea from [Resize missing.png depending upon style in paperclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933050/resize-missing-png-depending-upon-style-in-paperclip) but not the exact solution of the following scenario.

I have a **form** where user choose **image size** from dropdown, which is to upload and Then user upload the particular image.(I have validations for the same. used `Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.queued_for_write[:original].path)` for the same) .
I want to reduce the quality of **original Image** using convert option like (-strip -quality 90). Is there any way to create a style for original image which will be based on the selected value from the dropdown.

For eg. I have following Image sizes in dropdown
['1230 X 615'],['1230 X 390'],['1230 X 180'],['1230 X 240'],['1230 X 30'],['1020 X 180'],['1020 X 240'],['180 X 180'],['180 X 240'],['610 X 180'],['610 X 240'],['810 X 180']

Then how to create style if user select ['1020 X 240'] size from dropdown while uploading image?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help.
Following approach I used and it is working fine without proc,

The ' ' in {:large=>' '} are taking dropdown selected size  by default.

```
has_attached_file :image, { :styles => {:large => ''},
                                          :convert_options => { :large => '-strip -quality 80'}}.merge(SECTION_PATH).merge(BUCKET_PATH)
```

Answer (score 2):

As my thought you want to set image size whenever you are creating and updating object. You can try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029480/paperclip-attachments-with-dynamic-style-sizes-from-model) or [this one](http://www.ryanalynporter.com/2012/06/07/resizing-thumbnails-on-demand-with-paperclip-and-rails/) .